# git-flow: how to create a release branch without all features merged into develop?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, git-flow

In a normal **git-flow** process, the life cycle expects to have one or more **feature** branches that are joined back into **develop** when features are completed.

Then a **release** branch is created from develop branch when features are completed.

But let's suppose that I have to create multiple releases where:

- a first release needed for a **t0** instant contains all features
- another release needed for a **t1** instant contains some features (and not all of the t0 instant)

How can I do that, by the moment that **at t1 instant develop is already updated with all features implemented in t0**?

Is git-flow still applicable to this kind of context, and how?

Answer (score 0):

You want to branch off from `last-release` and call it `new-release`, then do `git cherry-pick` command to pick, from `develop` to this `new-release`, whatever merge commits (features) you need.